# Enviar varios campos "entry" en un signal_callback

Tags: c, ubuntu, interfaz-gráfica, gtk, entrada

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en gtk, en conjunto con C para crear una interfaz de inicio de sesion, sencilla.

En la primer parte del login unicamente valido los campos y los imprimo en consola, esta forma de enviar mas de un ENTRY en un callback lo hice con punteros dobles.

```
`GtkWidget *Datos[2];
    Datos[0] = IdEmpleado;
    Datos[1] = Password;
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(Btn_Aceptar), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Validar_Empleado),Datos); `
```

Y en la funcion unicamente hago esto solo para ir comprobando un poco como funciona GTK, dado que es mi primer programa en GTK

```
`void Validar_Empleado(GtkWidget *Btn, gpointer Datos){
    GtkWidget **w = (GtkWidget **)Datos;
    gchar *userName     = (gchar *)gtk_entry_get_text(w[0]); //Tenemos almacenado el texto que el usuario tecleo en el entry IdEmpleado
    gchar *password = (gchar *)gtk_entry_get_text(w[1]); //Tenemos almacenado el texto que el usuario tecleo en el entry Password
    printf("Numero de empleado... %s \n",userName);
    printf("Password capturado... %s \n",password);
}`
```

Cabe destacar que esta parte funciona como yo esperaba, sin embargo en la funcion Crear_Usuario donde genero una nueva ventana para dar de alta un usuario, intento el mismo procedimiento de mandar los Entry en forma de arreglo usando doble puntero, tal cual como lo hice en esta funcion, pero en esa aprte me falla, me arroja error

> IA__gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY(entry)' failed

Ya estuve tratando con puntero sencillo, inclusive con un solo widget y me da el mismo error, no se si al ser una pantalla diferente a la principal que esta en main, tenga que  cambiar la logica, agradeceria cualquier forma de apoyo, documentación, ejemplos, etc. Adjunto el codigo que tengo, aclaro no es lo mejor ni mas optimo pues apenas estoy conociendo la libreria y no he formalizado el codigo.

```
 void Crear_Empleado(){
    /*Colores definidos de manera global*/
    GdkColor Background, color2, red_btn, color_texto;//Definicion de color gtk para color de fondo
            Background.red= 18  * (65535/255);
            Background.blue=119 * (65535/255);
            Background.green= 1 * (65535/255); //Color fondo

            color2.red   = 195 * (65535/255);
            color2.blue  = 195 * (65535/255);
            color2.green = 195 * (65535/255); //Color etiquetas

            red_btn.red   = 179 * (65535/255);
            red_btn.blue  = 60 * (65535/255);
            red_btn.green = 60 * (65535/255); //Color btn cerrar

    GtkWidget *win_NuevoUsuario,*lbl_NumEmpleado,*NumEmpleado,*lbl_Password,*lbl_Password2,*Password,*Password2,*btn_Guardar,*btn_Cancelar,*lbl_admin,*check_admin;
    GtkWidget *Table;
    win_NuevoUsuario = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_modify_bg(win_NuevoUsuario, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &Background);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(win_NuevoUsuario), "Nuevo Empleado");
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(win_NuevoUsuario),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(win_NuevoUsuario,500,500);
    gtk_window_set_decorated(win_NuevoUsuario,FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_modal(win_NuevoUsuario,TRUE);
    //Creamos tabla para organizar los widget
        Table = gtk_table_new(30,30,FALSE);
        gtk_table_set_row_spacings(GTK_TABLE(Table), 15);
        gtk_table_set_col_spacings(GTK_TABLE(Table), 15);//Generar tabla con numero de columnas,filas,spacing,etc
    //Creamos los wiget y los posicionamos
        btn_Cancelar = gtk_button_new_with_label("Cancelar[x]");
            gtk_widget_modify_bg(btn_Cancelar,GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&red_btn);
            gtk_widget_modify_bg(btn_Cancelar,GTK_STATE_PRELIGHT,&red_btn);
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table), btn_Cancelar,29 , 30 , 28 , 30);
        btn_Guardar = gtk_button_new_with_label("Registrar Usuario");
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table), btn_Guardar ,27 , 29 , 28 , 30);
        lbl_NumEmpleado = gtk_label_new("Introduza el número de empleado: ");
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table), lbl_NumEmpleado,4,8,6,7);
            gtk_widget_modify_fg(lbl_NumEmpleado,GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&color2);
        lbl_Password = gtk_label_new("Introduza su contraseña: ");
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table), lbl_Password,4,5,10,11);
            gtk_widget_modify_fg(lbl_Password,GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&color2);
        lbl_Password2 = gtk_label_new("Confirme su contraseña: ");
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table), lbl_Password2,4,5,14,15);
            gtk_widget_modify_fg(lbl_Password2,GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&color2);
        NumEmpleado = gtk_entry_new();
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table),NumEmpleado,12,16,6,7);
        Password = gtk_entry_new();
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table),Password,12,16,10,11);
        Password2 = gtk_entry_new();
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table),Password2,12,16,14,15);
        lbl_admin = gtk_label_new("Usuario Administrador: ");
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table),lbl_admin,4,5,19,20);
            gtk_widget_modify_fg(lbl_admin,GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&color2);
        check_admin = gtk_check_button_new_with_label("Otorgar permisos de administrador");
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(Table),check_admin,13,14,19,20);
            gtk_widget_modify_fg(check_admin,GTK_STATE_NORMAL,&color2);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win_NuevoUsuario), Table);//Asignamos el container a la ventana
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(win_NuevoUsuario), 10);
    gtk_widget_show_all(win_NuevoUsuario);

    //Creacion de arreglo de widget para enviar datos
    GtkWidget *Datos[3];
    Datos[0] = NumEmpleado;
    Datos[1] = Password;
    Datos[2] = check_admin;

    //Signals
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (btn_Cancelar), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (Cerrar_Ventana),(gpointer) win_NuevoUsuario);
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (btn_Guardar), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (Registrar_Usuario), Datos);
}
```

Comment: Ok una solución temporal que encontré es usar un signal para enviar el valor de cada campo en un archivo de manera temporal, no es eficiente pero aun no entiendo como varia la dirección de los punteros, es decir, si hago la llamada a una ventana desde mi función main puedo usar un arreglo de widgets siempre y cuando implemente los punteros dobles, mas al hacer el call a una función para crearme una ventana desde otro lugar que no sea el main el método de los punteros dobles deja de funcionar.

Comment: Primero edita la pregunta la pregunta si encontraste una solución temporal pero no definitiva, si encuentras una definitiva publicala en respuestas.

Ahora estoy algo perdido, mencionas la función `crear_usuario`, pero no la veo, donde está ? ademas en que línea exactamente es el error? ademas la función `gtk_entry_get_text` retorna es el número de caracteres en GtkEntry, míralo [aquí](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-get-text).